# mongodb aggregration $match always return an array?

Tags: mongodb

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

The documentation says ***absolutely nothing*** about what type of object is returned.

I know however from testing that it returns an array if I get multiple documents back.

Must I use `$limit` if I only want to get back one document even though `$match` only matches one document (it seems to return an array in any case)?

Comment: Rather than ask an abstract question, it is better to show the document(s) you have as a sample and the result you want to achieve. `$match` is a pipeline operator that uses query conditions just like any MongoDB query. All it returns is the filtered result of the input it was given, just like any query does.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I realized my question is actually concerning the return value of the actual aggregation operation and not the actually $match.

Comment: The point is I see know valid question here at all and have voted on it as such. You can edit it to make it clear what you are asking as it presently is unclear. `$match` does exactly what it is described to do.

Comment: And I am absolutely positively sure that it is documented that [query results are returned as a cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor). ;) Think of it as a lazy-loaded list of documents.